# Updating Android SDK: "A folder failed to be moved."

Tags: android, sdk

While trying to update my Android SDK I am encountering this error when trying to install this particular package:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but move your SDK into c:\android-sdk\  Having it in \Program Files\ with that space in the directory is not going to help you. It will haunt you at every turn

Comment: I'd keep it out of /Program Files/ honestly that space in the path is just evil.

Comment: closing eclipse and then pressing yes worked for me, just had this problem :)

Comment: Solution for me was closing my emulator which was still running...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Eclipse, or even the SDK Manager itself, locks the folder. Running android.bat from the tools folder should do the trick.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that having it in "Program Files" wasn't the problem. I experienced the same issue with my directory located at `C:\Android\`. Simply exiting Eclipse and then running `C:\Android\tools\android.bat` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: It saved me...I was trying for fewer times.Thanks for the ans

Comment: It's worth noting that I needed to run android.bat as an admin or else I got the same error. Otherwise, works like a charm!

Comment: It's not just an Eclipse thing; I'm getting it in Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin.

Comment: Could having Android Studio simultaneously open be causing such a problem?

Comment: After having this problem in VS2013 / Xamarin and restarting, trying to open the SDK manager just results in an err msg ("Command did not execute successfully due to an unexpected exception. Please check the output window for additional information"). Here are the "More Details":

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   ... (etc.)

Comment: For me, just closing Android Studio and hitting "Yes" to continue the installation worked.

Comment: one important thing to mention, you have to run the android.bat as administrator.

Comment: It's also wise to see if no adb or java process is running any more on a Windows system (maybe also Linux, but this I don't know).  I had issues with this too...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839255/failed-to-rename-directory-tools-to-temp-toolpackage-old01-in-c-android-sdk-win it's also working for same issue...

Comment: Closing Eclipse fixed it for me

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer. For some reason, I can't locate the file android.bat. I searched it in file explorer, but there aren't any results. What should I do?

Comment: I have the [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/) tool installed, which shows the process that locks the folder. Indeed, Eclipse is locking the folder. Just closed it and it worked.

Answer (score 95):

This happens once in a while on my Windows SDK *(even when I don't have any antivirus or similar programs running, execute the SDK-Manager as an administrator and so on)*.

I just update the tools by hand in this case. Which means close the SDK-Manager after the error and open the `ANDROID_SDK\temp` folder. There should be a zip named `tools_R16.zip` or similar *(don't remember the exact name)*. Unzip that. You should end up with a `tools` folder. Copy all the files from this folder into `ANDROID_SDK\tools`. Overwrite when asked. And take a backup of the SDKs tools folder beforehand, just in case something explodes.

After that, start the SDK-Manager again. The tools version should be updated.

Comment: I will try this as a last resort.

Comment: I found that this approach could also be applied to updating the `android-sdk\extras\android\support` folder

Comment: This happened to me as well, so thanks for this answer. It is so damn frustrating, coming from XCode. Developing for Apple rocks. Developing for Android SUCKSSS. I just want to write some goddamn codes!!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well (update 22.2.1) - what a ludacris solution.

Answer (score 37):

If you launched the SDK Manager from Android Studio then all you need to do is close Android Studio.

I presumed the SDK Manager was a modal dialog that was part of Android Studio - not a separate program.

Comment: This worked for me. I closed Android Studio (which I had been running as admin) and clicked the retry button in the SDK manager, and it went right away.

Comment: worked for me as well.. I closed eclipse and it worked

Comment: Wow, this is ingenious. This worked for me. Your prediction seems accurate.

Answer (score 7):

thanks. this is how I fixed it:

I updated the tools by hand in this case. Which means close the SDK-manager after the error and open the folder android-sdk-windows folder.  Using LockHunter, unlock all programs from holding a lock on the android-sdk-windows\tools\ folder. http://lockhunter.com/?ver=&vertype=pro&sm=main_window_64

RENAME the android-sdk-windows\tools  folder beforehand to tools_DELETEME
There should be a zip named android-sdk-windows\temp\tools_r19-windows.zip. open that, You should see a tools folder in it. Copy that tools folder to android-sdk-windows\tools

After that, start the SDK-manager again. The tools version should be updated.

Answer (score 5):

When you install tools/softwares use SDK manager. But don't use it when update. Do right click -> Run as administrator on android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat file for updating tools. Always try to run commands as Administrator specially on Windows Vista/7/8. That'll fix most of permission issues etc...

Answer (score 4):

You probably started the SDK manager from eclipse? I encoutnered the same problem, and fixed it by manually opening the SDK manager from the directy tools.

Comment: No I'm starting it from outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Did you start it from the tools directory by using explorer, and is that window still open?

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to start it from within eclipse - as Administrator.

Comment: I wasted an hour or so trying to find and remove anti virus software and figure out what was locking the file only to remember windows 7 has that inferior run as administrator thing... what a pointless feature. But it worked for me despite being logged in as admin anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

well i had the same issue on windows 7 ... problem is that during the update it tries to rename the tools folder (inside the SDK folder) and that folder is used by a process "ADB" which is currently running ...

so you cannot do the update smoothly until you stop / kill that process ...

BTW copy pasting the new contents of tools folder from the temp would also work ...

Comment: Really Awesome trick.... Worked for me. Just killed adb process from Window Task Manager :)

Answer (score 2):

With windows 7, when "failed to install popup" appears kill the process called adb (from task manager ctrl+alt+del) then press "Yes" and stuff is being installed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running android.bat and got the same error.

What worked for me was using unlocker to unlock the \tools folder.

Comment: You need to run android.bat as an administrator. That's why you got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any essential files or folder opened/being used by other applications including explorer.

Comment: I did I even restarted my PC and made sure no processes or services were running that would do this.

Comment: Explorer did it for me :P

Answer (score 0):

I've read before, people take a copy of the platform-tools folder and run the update from a different location. This ensures you haven't got open the files it's trying to update.

Could also disable your antivirus for 5 minutes o0o0.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work either. Also, predictably, disabling antivirus did not help.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and probably Vista, run Eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was Windows 7 security.  I opened up the security on `C:\Program Files\Android` to EVERYONE with FULL access and it then worked.  I then removed EVERYONE after the update was complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a copy of the tools folder itself (keeping it at the same directory tree
level, thus "tools" and "tools-copy" were both in the "android-sdk-windows" folder).
Then ran Android.bat from that copy.

After the update just delete the tools-copy folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was `Failed to rename directory C:\devtools\android-sdk\system-images\android-21\google_apis\x86 to C:\devtools\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old01`. I deleted the C:\devtools\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old01 directory by hand (it was a leftover? I don't know) and it was able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Same error i got while updating sdk. It is because of targeted folder  locked (access permission is denied). 
    You can resolve it as follows in "Ubuntu" :-

Press ALT + F2 and type **'gksudo nautilus'** and navigate to the targeted folder like tools or extras and give **create and delete permission**.
    then update, every thing will be working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

First make a copy of tools folder in same directory (android-sdk or android-sdk-windows) then delete the original tools folder and then open the android.bat file by double clicking in tools-copy folder to launch sdk manager and install the tools.

If tools folder is not being deleted then use the unlocker [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/downloadnow.htm) to delete the folder and then open android.bat to update the tools.

After successful installation of tools delete the tools-copy folder.

Close Eclipse or Android Studio if open.

It worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

On my PC it was caused by monitor.exe running in the background. Terminating that proces solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Close the currently launched android studio window from task manager by going to the studioprocess (So when closed there are currently no active studio windows). Then go to Android studio in windows explorer, select the studio64/studio(if 32 bit OS) and right click and select run as administrator.
In one line - you need to **run Android Studio as a administrator**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps followed by me.

- Restart the computer.
- Open "C:\android\androidStudio\sdk\tools\android.bat" as admin.
- Now install packages should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I want to write my personal solution to the problem:

> Failed to rename directory C:\android-sdk\tools to C:\android-sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01.

Obviously I have had the same issue and every time the Android tools needs to be updated it's a nightmare.

None of the solutions I found googling the net worked for me up now, but this is a vital job to maintain Android SDK updated. So I started to find an alternative working way to solve this issue and I found it finally.... at least... it works for me, even if it is a bit tricky.

The basic problem is that the **android.bat** batch file comes from the ~\tools\ folder and it's still in memory (running) while the same ~\tools\ folder needs to be updated (in our case, renamed).

The problem is that the android.bat runs java to launch swt.jar (the SDK tool), and it remains uselessly waiting for completion of this java program.

You can edit the android.bat and see the call in the latest row of this batch:

```
call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

**The problem is the "call" CMD command. It waits for the called external program completion.**

But ther's another way to run external programs from a batch file: **the "start" command**. It launches an external program and terminates.

So I just replaced the "call" command with "start", so that after the change the latest row of my android.bat was:

```
start "" "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

**Note**: Keep the "" in between start and the application path. You can add text in those hyphens and this text will be the caption of the java.exe command window you will see after the changes. In my case I left the caption as an empty string but you can write there what you want.

After the changes, you can start the SDK and the android.bat will be no more waiting, leaving the SDK tool free to play (and rename the ~\tools\ folder without headaches).

Obviously, **after updating the SDK tools, you have to redo the same changes in the new, updated android.bat batch file**. This could be a bit unconfortable, but you'll have just to remember to make the changes before running the SDK tool and you'll have no other headaches while updating Android.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu following solved issue for me

1. cd [tools/directory/path]
2. sudo ./android

Answer (score 0):

Solved this on my side by killing the adb.exe in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I just stopped the emulator, and problem was solved.