# Travis CI can't create a directory for Android SDK

Tags: android, travis-ci

I setup the enviorment for Travis CI and added the .travis.yml to my Source Folder:

```
language : android

jdk: oraclejdk7

android:
 components:
    - build-tools-19.1.0

    # The SDK version used to compile the project
    - android-19

    - extra-google-google_play_services
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - addon-google_apis-google-19




before_install:
  - chmod +x gradlew

install:
  - true

script: ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Travis always download the build-tools etc. but it fails on rename the directory. The output is each time the same:

> Installing Archives:
>
> Preparing to install archives
>
> Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
>
> Installing SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4
>
> Failed to rename directory /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-19 to /usr/local/android->sdk/temp/PlatformPackage.old01.
>
> Failed to create directory /usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-19
>
> Done. Nothing was installed.

I know Travis CI for Android is beta.

**Edit:**

I probably know the issue. The problem is because of the SDK 19 is already installed, furthermore I only have to install the build-tools.

Comment: You are right. It's already installed https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/commits/master/ci_environment/android-sdk/attributes/default.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated response:** VM images already include fixed android-wait-for-emulator script and android SDK tools version 24.0.0 by default solving issues.

[Build Environment Updates - 2014-12-09](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/157#issuecomment-66310281)

**Outdated response:**

You are right. If you use container-based infrastructure and you need update to latest tools, you can find here an open issue for this:
https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2848

Default android-sdk folder is located at `/usr/local/android-sdk` and sudo is disabled. They are working on a Docker/BTRFS implementation that solves this issue.

Ayufan explains there that Docker by default uses AUFS which doesn't support all possible filesystem operations. I don't know the details about this specific issue.

Check my last response at the same link if you need upgrade to latest tools version (23.0.5, required by android-21) before they fix the filesystem/permission issue.

You can copy the `android-sdk` folder to a folder inside `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR` location using the next work around:

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_HOME=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/android-sdk
    - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/:${PATH}

before_install:
  - cp -R /usr/local/android-sdk-23.0.2 ./android-sdk
```

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables

So you keep already downloaded components and can move the `tools` folder where the `android` script and sdkmanager are located.

Other option is to just move the `tools` folder to a `temp` folder and update:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839359/1009132

Or a clean manual installation of latest tools creating two empty folders at the same level for `platforms` and `add-ons` using wget etc. The tools link:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-linux.zip

I know you currently don't need this response but probably people will need to install android-21 soon and find this issue.