# Error retrieving parent for item:No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. MY R.java is missing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, updating, r.java-file

Google has now Android Lollipop, I opened my sdk manager and decided to update couple of packages... It is furstrating me from 2 days. 
[Can't find theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

I have also tried this: [Failed to rename directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support)

Unsuccessful. I tried to download a new sdk from Google and install from scratch, did not work again.
Here is the error.

```
D:\~\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

 D:\~\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

D:\~\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839255/failed-to-rename-directory-tools-to-temp-toolpackage-old01-in-c-android-sdk-win
```

I will be very thankful if someone help me try running my eclipse Juno. I can also say that some of my old apps are working with lower version, but when I create a new one... error:

> `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`
>   It is not reading the android.suppor.v7

then if I reference it to my android app I have a ! sign and lots of mistakes like:

```
   D:\Android Studio\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
 D:\Android Studio\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
 D:\Android Studio\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Comment: Doing various things from answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro helped me. No errors anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me with the latest (21.0.2) version of Android Support Library the solution was to change the build target for appcompat_v7 project to API 21 (Android 5.0), clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem changing in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
```

and compile / target sdk to 19

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the target SDK to 21 and building the project?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Still the same. Everything from SDK Manager is installed. My opinion it that it failed while trying to put the new updates on the old packages. I have tried cleaning the project and then building it. Before one year I had the same problem but this time I cannot fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem... Perhaps one solution is to download an old sdk and not updating it.

Comment: Hey, I found a solution. Download and Install Android Studio from the "bin" folder. Then I downloaded installer for SDK Manager and from there I had to update the SDK Manager and then to download all the packages. Android Studio, doesn't give me any problems for now. 
I gave up on Eclipse. I am only wondering if i should try again Eclipse, since Android Studio start working...