# failed to rename directory eclipse in mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-sdk-tools

I am in trouble while downloading sdk s in eclipse . I am using mac . When I try installing or updating sdks , I got an error such that  */Users/psyfk/android-sdks/extras/android/support to /Users/psyfk/android-sdks/temp/ExtraPackage.old01.* Even though I gave permission to android-sdks file , I got this error . How can I fix that ?

Comment: This has also been discussed in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555131/updating-android-sdk-a-folder-failed-to-be-moved

Comment: I have looked at the link before and searched a lot in stackoverflow and other sites , but i could not find a solution ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Thought:**

Is your request going through Proxy Server? I faced similar problem in windows 7. I tried at home (outside proxy network) and it work like a charm. If you are under proxy then try checking in home network which doesn't go through

You can also setup the proxy in the adp and see whether it works.