# Why it is saying failed to install Sdk Manager?Why can't i install android studio?

Tags: android

SDK Manager: failed to install
-= Warning ! =-

> A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a
>   program is using that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your
>   anti-virus software.) Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus
>   software or close any running programs that may be accessing the
>   directory
>   'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23'. When
>   ready, press YES to try again. Note: you  can use --force to override
>   to yes. [y/n] =>

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555131/updating-android-sdk-a-folder-failed-to-be-moved

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete old sdk folder and try again. It worked for me