# Android Studio setup wizard failed after installation while downloading components

Tags: android

Here is the problem description shown while after installation android studio setup wizard runs and download components.... please help me out

SDK Manager: failed to install
-= Warning ! =-
A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a program is using that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.)
Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be accessing the directory 'H:\Android SDK\extras\android\m2repository'.
When ready, press YES to try again.
Note: you  can use --force to override to yes.
[y/n] =>

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8555131/2801822)

Answer (score 0):

The suggested post was not relevant to my problem. The solve was very simple. I ran android studio in administrator mood and life is good :)